# How do I share variables between members in a WinForms application (use static keyword)?

Tags: c#, winforms

How would I share variables between "Click on a button" functions inside a WinForms application? I tried reading about it, but I'm quite new to this and didn't really get it clear - from what I understand, I have to use the static keyword?
I don't really know how to explain it, so I'll just show some simple code (that has mistakes in it, since I don't know how to make it work):

```
namespace stackoverflow
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = "Not clicked!";
            int number = 0;
        }
        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Clicked button 1.";
            number = 1;
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Clicked button 2.";
            number = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

How would I make the number actually update in the whole class...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps when you understand what the accessibility types mean.

When something is declared as static, it means that the variable occupies a single place in memory for the lifetime of the application. Calling or assigning to that variable will only ever affect a single memory location/offset.

Non-Static variables are, as you say, 'members' of an instance of a type.
The difference in how they are accessed is that you would need to prefix the variable with the instance of the class which contains the variable.

```
theFormInstance.Number = 5;
```

or
    this.Number=5;

Static variables however, are referenced by using the type name.
I like to think of it as 'belonging'
A static variable 'belongs to the type' where a non-static 'belongs to an instance of the type'

```
Form1.Number= 5;
```

While yes, you can use Static variables, you shouldn't need to in this particular example because the variable you are attempting to alter resides within the same Form class as the click events.

As long as the variable is declared outside of the click event handlers/methods, but within the enclosing class - then all methods within the Form1 class will have access to the variable.

Note - I suspect that because you were clicking on buttons, you assumed that the buttons wouldn't have visibility to the form class, because they are other controls etc.
The thing to remember is that while the buttons are triggering the event handler 'click' to execute, it is still the Form that is running the code.
Eg:

```
MessageBox.Show(this.Name);
```

This will return the Form's name, no matter where you execute it within the Form, whether it be in a buttons click event or in a form load event.

If you wanted to grab the button from inside an event handler, then you could use the 'sender' variable to reference the button.
(You would need to cast it to the proper type though.

Eg

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        label1.Text = "Clicked "+btn.Name;
        number = 2;
    }
```

Anyway, know this goes off in a few directions, but hope its informative and gives you an insight into accessibility within forms.
Just remember - Controls live within the Form, so they have equal access to all variables declared within the form - as long as they are inside the form but outside of method bodies.

Comment: "it means that the variable occupies a single place in memory for the lifetime of the application." - static is about _scope_ not _memory_.  There's nothing stopping the managed runtime form moving the memory to another location.  The point of static is that it is shared by all class instances.

Answer (score 2):

They don't have to be `static` since you're using the same instance of the `Form1` class.  Since the event handlers are properties of the *form* and not the buttons, you can use form-level member form all event handlers:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int number = 0;  // field at the form level
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = "Not clicked!";
    }
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Clicked button 1.";
        number = 1;
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Clicked button 2.";
        number = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the same instance of the class. There's no need to use `static`, all you need is a simple field, rather than using a local:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  int number;

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the int number = 0; in the class declaration and not in the constructor. (E.g. put it between the public Form1() and public partial class Form1 { lines)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the number outside form function like

```
namespace stackoverflow
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = "Not clicked!";
        }

        int number = 0;

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Clicked button 1.";
            number = 1;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Clicked button 2.";
            number = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically to regurgitate what everyone else is saying:

Either create a class and work directly from that that contains your properties and fields, pass that between your forms. I wouldn't put a field/property anywhere in your Form.cs except the top, just to keep it clean really. I would check out WPF and the MVVM pattern to be honest, this is where it excels at and it's really the future. I went the route of Winforms/WebForms and now only develop using WPF/MVC and really wish I would have just skipped the other stuff. Just my two cents to be honest.

Answer (score -2):

Declare the variable at class level rather than locally.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int number = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        ...
```