# How to pass a string from OnLoad event to on Clickevent in C#?

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-forms-designer

I have an `onLoad` event and it contains the variable which takes data from the database and now I need to pass that string to an `onclick` event of a button so that whenever it is pressed I can perform operations. I need to access word variable from load to `onclick`.

```
using System;    
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.ComponentModel;    
using System.Data;    
using System.Drawing;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Text;    
using System.Threading.Tasks;    
using System.Windows.Forms;    
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;    
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        public string word, alphabets;
        public int chances, score;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chances = 8;
            score = 0;
            alphabets = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int wordid = rnd.Next(1, 127);
            label12.Text = chances.ToString();
            label13.Text = score.ToString();
            try
            {
                string myConnection1 = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=amit;";
                MySqlConnection myConn1 = new MySqlConnection(myConnection1);
                myConn1.Open();
                int count = 0;
                var cmd = new MySqlCommand(" select words from  gamers.gamewords where id='" + wordid + "';", myConn1);
                string word = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                int length = word.Length;
                label4.Text = length.ToString();
                label7.Text = alphabets;
                label14.Text = word;
                myConn1.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Code for Game Begins
            int i = 0, j = 0;
            int lengthcount = 0;
            string choice = textBox1.Text;
            string guess;
            label14.Text = word + "**";
            //  for (i = 0; i<word.Length; i++)
            /*    {
                    if (word[i] == choice[0])
                    {
                        label14.Text = "Good Guess! You Scored a point";
                        lengthcount++;
                        score += 5;
                        guess = choice;
                        label9.Text= guess;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chances--;
                        guess = "______";
                        if (chances == 0)
                        {
                            label14.Text = "You Lost the Game! Turns Over";
                            button1.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            label14.Text = "Sorry! Try Again";
                        }
                    }

                }*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I share variables between members in a WinForms application (use static keyword)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846041/how-do-i-share-variables-between-members-in-a-winforms-application-use-static-k)

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `button1_Click` like a method, but you can't pass a value to it directly, because the `Click` event are handled by the default `EventHandler`, so you have just the two parameters: `object sender` and `EventArgs e`:

```
button1_Click(sender, e);
```

But you can use a property (or a field / variable) in the `Form2` class, to hold an value from the `Form2_Load` method, and after read then in the `button1_Click` method:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    // ...
    private string ValueToHold { get; set; }
    // ...
    public void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
        ValueToHold = "something";
        // ...
    }
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
        // Use the ValueToHold here!
        // ...
    }
}
```